# How can I check if an input's value matches and display some text if it doesn't?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery script to check if a value (a postcode) typed into an input field matches any of the values I have. At the moment, when a value is typed into the input field, it changes the visibility of a div (which has an ID of the particular postcode) from `none` to `inline-block` if a value matches (as shown in the code below), so if I type 3138 it changes the visibility of a `p` tag with an id of "3138" from `display: none` to `display: inline-block`.

I would like to show a message if a matching value isn't found. At the moment if a value that doesn't match is inputted then no message is displayed, which tells me I need a sort of `else` statement.

I tried Googling `if`/`else` statements but I'm not even sure if that's the right thing to be searching for...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#postcode").keyup(function() {
    $("#3138").css("display", this.value == "3138" ? "inline-block" : "none"),
      $("#3136").css("display", this.value == "3136" ? "inline-block" : "none");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="postcode-checker">
  <div>
    <p>Enter your postcode and find out what day we deliver to your area: <input type="text" id="postcode" placeholder="Postcode..."></p>
    <p id="3138" style="display:none;">
      Your Delivery Day is <strong>TUESDAY</strong>
    </p>
    <p id="3136" style="display:none;">Your Delivery Day is <strong>FRIDAY</strong>
      <p id="3136" style="display:none;">Your Delivery Day is <strong>FRIDAY</strong> https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62359754/edit# </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've also put together a [codepen](https://codepen.io/justbrown1980/pen/KKVMzWN).

Comment: Did you already find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the same logic and add another paragraph:

```
<p id="errorMsg" style="display:none;" >
      Error:<strong>no match</strong>
    </p>
```

```
$("#errorMsg").css("display", (this.value != "3138" && this.value != "3136")  ? "inline-block" : "none");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function that checks if the input value is one of the postcodes you have. I added a button (`id="btn-check"`), when clicking, the output should be displayed in a new `<p></p>` tag (`id="p-delivery"`) (you can change this to what you prefer). If the outcome would be a postcode, you could do some calculations with it (like on what day the item gets delivered), if it would return `false` you could display an error message. Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn-check").click(function () {
        const postcodes = [3468, 3138, 4578, 3136]; // Example postcodes.
        const checkPostcodes = check(postcodes); // Call check() on postcodes.
        if (checkPostcodes != false) { // If postcode (not false) is returned.
            $('#p-delivery').text('Delivery possible'); // Delivery is possible.
            if(checkPostcodes > 3000 && checkPostcodes < 4000){ // If postcode is between 3000 and 4000
                $('#p-delivery').text('Delivery on friday for postcode ' + checkPostcodes + '.'); // Example.
            }
        } else {
            $('#p-delivery').text('Delivery not possible.'); // Otherwise not possible.
        }
    })
})

function check(postcodes) {
    const postcode = $('#postcode').val();

    let status;
    for (let i = 0; i < postcodes.length; i++) {
        if (postcode == postcodes[i]) { // Loop postcodes.
            return postcodes[i]; // Return the matching postcode.
        } else {
            status = false; // Otherwise not.
        }
    }
    return status; // Return false if no match.
}
```

```html
<p id="p-delivery"></p>
<button id="btn-check">CHECK</button>
```